# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll in send data by serialport

Tags: serial-port, invalidoperationexception

i am trying to send a string to serial port but i got An unhandled exception of type  'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
my code is simple :
serialport.write("110");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us, and don't forget to tell us what language you're programming in.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article properly.
You seem to have written to a port that is not open.

[SerialPort.Write Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8)

> Exceptions
>   **InvalidOperationException**
>   The specified port is not open.